# Disable auto-generation of [Serializable] attribute by VS2015 C# compiler

Tags: c#, linq, serialization, visual-studio-2015

VS2015 C# compiler emits `[Serializable, CompilerGenerated]` attributes on all auto-generated helper classes for LINQ queries. Prior versions of Visual Studio used to emit only `[CompilerGenerated]` attribute on such classes.

Is there a way to disable auto-generation of `[Serializable]` attribute in VS2015? The reason is that our obfuscator refuses to rename classes marked as `[Serializable]`, although in our case it is 100% safe because we don't use serialization.

Here is the example of auto code generated by older compilers:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c
{
    public static readonly Program.<>c <>9 = new Program.<>c();
    // ... more stuff here
}
```

Here is what VS2015 emits:

```
[Serializable, CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c
{
    public static readonly Program.<>c <>9 = new Program.<>c();
    // ... more stuff here
}
```

I want the compiler to stop generating that `[Serializable]` attribute. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a simple dnlib-based tool that parses compiled assembly and changes the `Serialized` property of every class with the [CompilerGenerated] attribute to false. Seems to work well enough for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I hesitated to post this... maybe i'm wrong, but i'm sure this can lead to the right direction.

So Roslyn is the compiler which generates the code (that's the default compiler in VS2015), and it's open source (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn)). The LabdaRewriter.cs ([here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/5a97d296d3dedbe6cc7c580835da32adb3252d23/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Lowering/LambdaRewriter/LambdaRewriter.cs)) contains the logic which rewrites the lambda into the class and does all the magic. In the `GetStaticFrame` method there is this line:

```
_lazyStaticLambdaFrame = new LambdaFrame(_topLevelMethod, scopeSyntaxOpt: null, methodId: methodId, closureId: closureId);
```

Now `LamdaFrame` is the class which represents the generated class (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/5a97d296d3dedbe6cc7c580835da32adb3252d23/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Lowering/LambdaRewriter/LambdaFrame.cs)) (in your case `<>c` which gets the  SerializableAttribute).

Remember the `scopeSyntaxOpt: null` part from the constructor parameter!

Here is the constructor:

```
internal LambdaFrame(MethodSymbol topLevelMethod, CSharpSyntaxNode scopeSyntaxOpt, DebugId methodId, DebugId closureId)
            : base(MakeName(scopeSyntaxOpt, methodId, closureId), topLevelMethod)
{
            _topLevelMethod = topLevelMethod;
            _constructor = new LambdaFrameConstructor(this);
            this.ClosureOrdinal = closureId.Ordinal;
        // static lambdas technically have the class scope so the scope syntax is null 
        if (scopeSyntaxOpt == null)
        {
            _staticConstructor = new SynthesizedStaticConstructor(this);
            var cacheVariableName = GeneratedNames.MakeCachedFrameInstanceFieldName();
            _singletonCache = new SynthesizedLambdaCacheFieldSymbol(this, this, cacheVariableName, topLevelMethod, isReadOnly: true, isStatic: true);
        }
        ...
}
```

And there is one property called `IsSerializable`:

```
    // display classes for static lambdas do not have any data and can be serialized.
    internal override bool IsSerializable
    {
        get { return (object)_singletonCache != null; }
    }
```

As you see in the constructor this _`singletonCache` is basically never null when the instance is created in the `GetStaticFrame` method (I think this is the case where you do not capture values from the outside in you LINQ expression (FIXME)) , therefore it returns true, and I think based on this property the generated class get's the SerializableAttribute.

So I think at the moment this is hard-coded and you cannot change this, unless you touch the Roslyn source code and improve this....

Comment: Thank you for this research, I suspected something like that. I guess the easiest is to just write a tool to modify compiled assembly

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good workaround for your case. Btw. I would suggest to add the Roslyn tag to your question... People who are much more familiar with the code-base then me are sometimes hanging out here... maybe they have a better solution. I also posted an edit with this, but it was rejected...